# How to find resource leak in Ant script when called from Java

Tags: java, debugging, file-io, ant, resource-leak

[Note: I figured the resource leak out (see my answer below), but I'm still curious as to why command-line ant did terminate but in-java ant did not]

I'm calling a complex ant target from within my Java program. It runs through without errors. But in the end the program does not terminate. I call the program from NetBeans via maven execute.

If I call the ant target from command line, it does terminate. If I write `System.exit(0);` at the end of my program, it terminates.

So, I assume that either I am missing some call to the ant library that tells it to close all streams etc. or that I have a resource leak in my ant script. I think its a resource leak as `jstack` reports an open stream (see below) - how could I find out whats open there?

Here is my call to ant:

```
public boolean callToAnt() {
File antFile = new File("C:\somepath\build.xml");
File logfile = new File("C:\somepath\antlog.log");
File projectBasePath = antFile.getParentFile();
try (PrintStream logfilestream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(logfile))) {
        Project project = new Project();
        project.setUserProperty("ant.file", antFile.getAbsolutePath());
        project.init();
        ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
        ProjectHelper.configureProject(project, antFile);
        project.setBaseDir(projectBasePath);
        project.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
        project.setProperty("foo", "bar"); // some properties
        project.addBuildListener(getDefaultLogger(logfilestream));
        project.executeTarget("myTarget");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(this.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I tried calling `project.fireBuildFinished(null);` but that didn't change anything.

If I comment out the ant part the program terminates. If I leave away the logger, it still won't terminate.

I'm leaving away the ant script itself as it is spread over many files and very complex. My goal here is to learn how to find the resource leaks myself more then just fixing this one problem.

The logfile doesn't contain any errors as well (ending with "BUILD SUCCESSFUL").

I called `jstack` on the process when it stalled and this is the result:

```
2015-03-23 09:51:40
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode):

"Thread-1" #10 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x15b14400 nid=0x120c waiting on condition [0x152ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.InputStreamPumper.run(InputStreamPumper.java:69)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-3" #12 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x15bb9000 nid=0x15b4 runnable [0x164af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:224)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:105)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Thread-2" #11 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x15bb4000 nid=0x10fc runnable [0x1506f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        - locked <0x049b25b8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:105)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x14cbb000 nid=0x17f4 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x14caa000 nid=0xcf4 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x14ca9000 nid=0x16c8 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x14ca6000 nid=0x13fc runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x0081f000 nid=0x1324 in Object.wait() [0x14ebf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x09bfc108> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
        - locked <0x09bfc108> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x0081a000 nid=0xca0 in Object.wait() [0x14c1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x09bfc2a8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
        - locked <0x09bfc2a8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000acc00 nid=0x12f4 runnable [0x0221e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitForInterruptibly(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(ProcessImpl.java:449)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:347)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:610)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:352)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x00815800 nid=0xa44 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x14cc4c00 nid=0x9b4 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 38
```

Comment: I figured it out with the Debugger. The Ant Script called an external library that started a ThreadPool but did not close it in the end. Thus the Threads kept lingering and prevented the program from termination. I have no clue why that does not happen in ant when I call it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will have to use profiler and attach to running ant script. Analize thread dumps and/or have trace of object allocations. This should reveal any leaks in no time, assuming that there is one. JVisualVm is shipped with SDK so you can use it. I think it is quite decent profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger. Its very tiresome and will take some time but then you will find out whats the problem.

You have to step through any classes that gets called - be glad that ant, maven etc. are all open source so you can download the sources through NetBeans. (Open the Dependencies in the Project and right click everything thats interesting and select 'Download sources')

Then you step through your program until you notice that something gets left open. The fact that `System.exit(0)` works, but letting the program just run indicates that an Object reference did not get cleaned up. While the debugger runs you can see the running Threads of the tool in the Debugging View. If there are any left in the end you have to find out where they started.

To do that step through the program until one of them pops up. Remember the position in code and state, create Breakpoints as appropriate, stop the program and restart - this time stop before the line that caused the additional Thread to appear and step into that method, repeat.